# How to optimize hyperparameters with RandomSearchCV or GridSearchCV in neural network for beginners?

Tags: python, time-series, generator, gridsearchcv

I'm using Python. How can the GridSearchCV or RandomSearchCV be easily integrated in the network training?
I receive the following error code:

AttributeError: 'RandomizedSearchCV' object has no attribute 'fit_generator'

Does anyone have a simple idea to get around this error?

```py
def train_test_splitting(df):
    x_train,x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 123, shuffle = False)
    return [x_train,x_test, y_train, y_test]


def preprocessing_nn(df,time_period_window, num_oberservations_per_batch ,number_training_features):
    
    TimeseriesGenerator(features, target, length = 6 , sampling_rate = 1, batch_size =1)[0]
    
    win_length = time_period_window #Wie viele Datenpunkte
    batch_size = num_oberservations_per_batch # wie viele Beobachtungswertee pro Iteration
    num_features = number_training_features
    
    nn_train_generator= TimeseriesGenerator(x_train, y_train, length = win_length , sampling_rate = 1, batch_size = batch_size)
    nn_test_generator= TimeseriesGenerator(x_test, y_test, length = win_length , sampling_rate = 1, batch_size = batch_size)
    
    return [nn_train_generator, nn_test_generator]


#Applying Functions:

x_train,x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_splitting(df)
nn_train_generator,nn_test_generator = preprocessing_nn(df,time_period_window, num_oberservations_per_batch ,number_training_features)

def create_LSTM_network(optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=120, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(time_period_window,number_training_features)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(units=120, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = "relu"))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['mae'])
    return model

#Wrapper für Scikit Learn zur Benutztung von Randomised CV
LSTM_neural_network = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_LSTM_network, verbose=1)

#Create hyperparameter space
epochs = sp_randInt(10,500)
batches = sp_randInt(10,100)
optimizers = ['rmsprop','adam','sgd']
hyperparameters = dict(optimizer = optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size = batches)

#RandomSearchCV - Creation
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = LSTM_neural_network, param_distributions=hyperparameters,
                          cv= 2, n_iter = 5, n_jobs =-1)

grid_result  = grid.fit(nn_train_generator, epochs = 50, 
                              validation_data = nn_test_generator,
                              shuffle=False,
                              callbacks=[early_stopping])
print(); print(grid_result.best_params_)


AttributeError: 'RandomizedSearchCV' object has no attribute 'fit_generator'
```